# Clarification of Cauchy-Goursat Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Cauchy-Goursat:
If $f$ is analytic in a simply connected domain D, then $\int_{c}f(z) dz=0 $ for any closed curve $c$ in D.

However, I have seen questions where Cauchy-Goursat has been used when the function is just analytic **in** and **on** a closed curve C. Where are the simply connected regions in these situations? I know that Cauchy Gourmet can be applied to curves within C but why is it possible on C itself?

Comment: The key is any closed curve.

Comment: Yes but it is a closed curve in D. How about the boundary of D? Is C itself in any simply connected region? If so it that region determined by the open balls wise centers are points n the curve?